# NaNs warning en ZAP model

Tags: r

Intentando construir un modelo inflado a ceros R me devuelve el siguiente mensaje:

> Warning message: In sqrt(diag(object$vcov)) : NaNs produced

Que básicamente supone que la mayoría de mis estadísticos aparecen como Na. Las recomendaciones que leo en otros foros son re escalar las variables numéricas. Lo he hecho y pese a que mejora, siguen apareciendo Na que me impiden interpretar nada o seguir modelando.

```
tabla <- read.table("Dataset_pulido-basura.csv", sep=";", dec=".", header=T, na.strings="NA") 
f1<- formula(presencias ~ distancia|distancia+habitat+ganado) 
Zap1 <- hurdle(f1, dist = "poisson",link = "logit", data = tabla)
```

Comment: Antes que nada, por las dudas te comento que se trata de un warning, eventualmente podrías quitarlo para qu

Comment: Perdón, estoy con la app de Android y no puedo editar el comentario anterior. Te decía, que puedes hacer que no se informe. De todas formas, deberías pegar un ejemplo mínimo de código para poder analizar.

Comment: Gracias Patricio, disculpa no haber posteado codigo.

Sería algo asi:

_tabla <- read.table("Dataset_pulido-basura.csv", sep=";", dec=".", header=T, na.strings="NA")_

_f1<- formula(presencias ~ distancia|distancia+habitat+ganado)
Zap1 <- hurdle(f1, dist = "poisson",link = "logit", data = tabla)_

Donde presencias, distancia y ganado son numéricas y habitat categórica de cinco niveles.

Answer (score 0):

Sin los datos es difícil hacer un análisis, lo que si puedo decirte es que el problema se produce por algún valor en los regresores que terminan produciendo que la diagonal de la matriz de varianza/covarianza del modelo tenga algún valor en negativo. Esto lo puedes verificar de la siguiente forma:

```
diag(Zap1$vcov)
```

si hay algún valor negativo eso confirmaría esta teoría, ya que en definitiva se esta haciendo una raiz cuadrada de un negativo, lo que termina produciendo un `NaN`.

La solución del problema está en analizar en detalle los datos con los que alimentas el modelo, o como te decía, en definitiva se trata de un Warning, por lo que si el mismo no tiene consecuencias sobre lo esperado, bien podrías ignorarlo mediante:

```
options(warn=-1)
```